# Texmaker TexLive 2014 does nothing

Tags: pdftex, texlive, texmaker

I am using Texmaker 4.3 (downloaded from their website) and Texlive 2014 (also downloaded) on Ubuntu 12.4 fork ElementaryOS in 64bit.

I recently completely reinstalled my OS and compiling a PDF in Texmaker does not work (it did work before the reinstall, but that may have been Texlive 2013 or even 2012, though I am not sure. also it was 32bit).
By "not working" I mean that if I click the PDFLaTeX button, my PC works and I see latex output, but there is no pdf created (and if one exists previously, it's not changed). I see no conpile errors.
I google a bit, but I was not able to find a solution. My configuration of Texmaker is

```
latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

Some more information:
Compiling works in Terminal (with pdflatex name.tex). 
For the current document I don't have a bibliography, but in general I use biblatex with biber.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Others might be able to identify your problem by looking at the `.log` file produced when you click the PDFLaTeX button.

Comment: No log file is created and actually, I forgot to mention this, when I press the button I get a pop up about logfile not being found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general PATH changes are better off added in `~/.profile` (for personal use) or added to `/etc/profile` or added in the front of the `PATH` variable in `/etc/environment`. In any case **always** make a back up first.

Why not `~/.bashrc`? It will only be executed in a bash context. So when an editor is started from a menu, and it makes a system call to start LaTeX, it is not a bash shell the calls LaTeX, or at least not one that has read `~/.bashrc`.

Adding it to say `~/.profile`, then this is global (for the user) and is read once and for all at login.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by something very simple: In Options -> Configure Texmaker I typed the full path for pdflatex's and lualatex's and biber's binary. I got the full path by opening the terminal and typing "which [pdflatex|lualatex|biber]".
It works now.

However, I don't understand WHY providing the full path to Texmaker is necessary. In Terminal, I can use these binaries just fine. I thought Texmaker makes use of the same environment variables (or whatever these are called in Linux) as the terminal. Or do I have to configure a search path for Texmaker individually? Then this might be the reason.
I am still looking for more ideas to understand this behaviour, even though I found a work around.

Comment: Let me make one guess: Did you add the TeXLive PATH to `~/.bashrc` and afterwards start TeXmaker from a menu or by double clicking on a `.tex` file? That will not work. The PATH change should go into `~/.profile` (then log out and in againg for it to take effect).

Comment: Yes, it is indeed in ~/.bashrc. I'll try your answer. Is adding them to ~/.profile the right thing to do for all paths to binaries?

Comment: I would guess so. `~/.bashrc` only makes it available for stuff that runs through a shell that also remembers to run ~/.bashrc`. BTW: where did you learn that you should add the PATH change to `~/.bashrc` in the first place (we'd like to have some of those resources updated)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. It works indeed! As for adding the PATH to .bashrc: I never knew about this .profile file. I thought that .bashrc is the best place for everything ... and I knew about /etc/profile for global changes. But thanks to you, next time I'll know better about what to do. You should post this solution as an answer, I think. Then I can accept it.

Comment: I've added a writeup